# How does Photoshop Camera RAW/Lightroom's Color Calibration Tool Work?

Tags: image-processing, colors, photoshop, hsl, image-effects

I want to try and reverse engineer the camera calibration panel in the camera raw filter in Photoshop/Lightroom.

[Photoshop Colour Calibration Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVnSW.png)

It can create some pretty cool effects, so I want to write a program what will help automate these effects. I've attempted to try and figure out how it works, it seems to work differently from the HSL colour adjustment methods in that just moving the "Blue Primary" slider seems to affect all colours not just the blue hues (it even affects some colours that begin as solid red).

I've tried to graph out the sort of function this would do, since it seems to do something along the lines of shifting the hue of the actual blue colour in RGB to be whatever you shift the hue by, but I'm not sure what this actually means.

Here's an [unmodified graph of hues relating to RGB values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwdT8.png).

Here's the same graph, [but by shifting the blue primary hues all the way to the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STDn3.png).

I know it's doing more than just hue shifting, since just running the filter on a hue spectrum with L/S both at 100% seems to actually change the lightness and saturation on some of the hues, see images linked below for an example.

[Regular Hue Spectrum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRVfO.png)

[Hue Spectrum with Blue Primary slider all the way to the left.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1RzI.png)

Is there any other open source software that does something like this that I can look to for code, or possibly an idea of how this actually works under the hood?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out (at least what I believe they're doing). So if anyone else has the same question, what they're doing is by taking advantage of the chromaticity coordinates for each of the RGB colours in the RGB -> XYZ colour space conversion. So when shifting the hue of the blue coordinate, I think they're first just shifting the hue of the blue in HSL, then taking that colour of the shifted hue, converting it into XYZ, then projecting the XYZ onto XY to get the chromaticity coordinate for the shifted blue. Then to apply that to an image, just converting from RGB to XYZ with the shifted coordinate, and converting back into RGB with the unshifted XYZ conversion matrix.

Comment: nice sleuthing! did you ever happen to open source this approach somewhere or write-up more details? :)